# UIBarButtonItem as a BackButton

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have two view controllers. The first is the login page and the second is the user cabinet. When I sign in and go to second view I can see back button "FirstController" at the Navigation Bar. But I don't need of this button and I want to have rect button as a "Sign Out".

Question: how can I set rect button "Sign Out" as a back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide UINavigationbar's Hide button while requesting to load from login page & while loading "FirstController", initialize your UIBarButtonItem with custom view - UIButton (Sign Out button) and also set selector to respond as click on "Sign Out".

**Sample Code:**

To Hide back button:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

To add "Sign Out" button:

```
-(void)setMySignOut
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_logout_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLogoutClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}

-(void)btnLogoutClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // your logic goes here...
}
```

Comment: I mean you didn't understand me. I explain it simply. I want to have back button with rectangle form

Comment: @Multirut - What I understand is, you want a rectangle button instead of the default back button, right? And I have given description & sample code for the same. You can set UIButton's size & shape as you desire.